# Adding the Angular Material theme to Stackblitz Projects with Angular 17?

Tags: css, angular, sass, stackblitz

In previous versions of Stackblitz there used to be a `styles.css` file and to use one of the prebuilt themes we could just add an import to `styles.css` like this.

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

However with the latest Stackblitz which uses `global_styles.css` this errors.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-od474b?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css

How do we import themes in Stackblitz with Angular 17?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v17 uses the application builder when creating a project from scratch.

This builder relies on Esbuild which doesn't support "~" in path (it's a webpack feature).

Remove the `~` and you're good.

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Also you're missing the `MatButtonModule` in your example and dont forget to import the icons font.